# Why does the for loop return None?

Tags: python

I'm working an exercise from Code Academy to iterate through the `shopping_list`.
Why does the following code result return an extra `None` in the result?

```
shopping_list = ["banana","apple"]

stock = { "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = { "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

# Write your code below!
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for x in food:
        print x
        total += prices[x]
compute_bill(shopping_list)
```

Comment: Your function will return `None`. Perhaps your environment is just displaying the return value after the function runs

Comment: # Write your code below!
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for x in food:
        print x
        total += prices[x]
    return total
print "total:"+str(compute_bill(shopping_list))

Comment: After the second example of this section of the Tutorial - <http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions>.

Answer (score 2):

```
shopping_list = ["banana","apple"]

stock = { "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = { "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

# Write your code below!
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for x in food:
        print x
        total += prices[x]
    return total
print(compute_bill(shopping_list))
```

You need use `return` statement to get the result of the function `compute_bill`.